# How to get DNS to resolve the same from localhost as from remote?

Tags: dns

I'm trying to create a home automation system that watches my dog during the day while I'm at work. My goals for this project are to learn a bit about DNS, file serving, and the RaspberryPi.

My hardware setup is as so:

- 1 RaspberryPi (camera enabled, and planning to use this as the web server behind my home router).
- 1 digital ocean mini instance (ubuntu12.04 with DNS provided via BIND).
- 1 macbook (testing DNS with this for now, but will later be using iPhones most commonly).

I'd like to use bubby.com as the domain name. This works when I query from my digital ocean server. However, if I try from my laptop, I get back a different ip.

**Tests from digital ocean instance:**

1. dns settings (contents of /etc/resolv.conf)
       nameserver x.x.x.x
       nameserver 8.8.8.8
       nameserver 8.8.4.4
2. nslookup of bubby.com
       **nslookup bubby.com**

   ```
   Server:     x.x.x.x
   Address:    x.x.x.x#53
   Name:   bubby.com
   Address: y.y.y.y
   ```

   (1 and 2 are correct as far as I can tell)

**Tests from macbook**

3. DNS settings from wifi (retrieved from Network Preferences): 
   nameservers x.x.x.x, 8.8.8.8
4. nslookup of bubby.com
       **nslookup bubby.com**

   ```
   Server:     x.x.x.x
   Address:    x.x.x.x#53
   Non-authoritative answer:
   Name:   bubby.com
   Address: 216.21.239.197
   ```

Could someone help me explain why I get different results from the same dns server that are showing different addresses, even though the server/address is correct for the dns server?

Update 1: Reran test of nslookup
        **date && nslookup bubby.com**

```
    Sat Aug 20 05:57:01 PDT 2016
    Server:     x.x.x.x
    Address:    x.x.x.x#53
    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   bubby.com
    Address: 216.21.239.197
```

Dig bubby.com from laptop
**date && dig bubby.com @192.241.227.149**

```
    Sat Aug 20 06:06:27 PDT 2016

    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> bubby.com @x.x.x.x
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18813
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;bubby.com.         IN  A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    bubby.com.      3600    IN  A   216.21.239.197

    ;; Query time: 132 msec
    ;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
    ;; WHEN: Sat Aug 20 06:06:27 2016
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Dig hubby.com from digital ocean server with dns
**date && dig bubby.com @x.x.x.x**

```
    Sat Aug 20 13:12:36 UTC 2016

    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> bubby.com @x.x.x.x
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38404
    ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;bubby.com.         IN  A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    bubby.com.      604800  IN  A   y.y.y.y

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    bubby.com.      604800  IN  NS  ns.bubby.com.

    ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    ns.bubby.com.       604800  IN  A   y.y.y.y

    ;; Query time: 2 msec
    ;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
    ;; WHEN: Sat Aug 20 13:12:36 2016
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```

Update 2: DNS lookup from laptop while specifying another DNS server
        **date && nslookup ip.smartydns.com 87.117.205.40**

```
    Sat Aug 20 09:12:09 PDT 2016
    Server:     87.117.205.40
    Address:    87.117.205.40#53
    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   ip.smartydns.com
    Address: 82.196.5.38
```

Comment: Can you repeat the test from your macbook (that nslookup output looks like it is from before bubby.com zone was configured on 192.241.227.149), and also try `dig bubby.com @192.241.227.149`

Comment: One more test please: what is the output (on your laptop) of `nslookup ip.smartydns.com 87.117.205.40`?

Comment: Did you consider editing your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - yes, I thought about sharing hosts files, but in the future I'm planning on expanding my home network, and so I'd prefer to get DNS to work properly.

Comment: @DusanBajic Updated the main post with the most recent test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `dig` output from your laptop, notice the `AUTHORITY: 0`. The reason for this is because this answer is not coming form your Digital Ocean instance (I have tested form several different locations, and I always get the same results as you get when you test from the instance itself), but from some other DNS server that is not authoritative for `bubby.com`.

The final [smartyDNS](https://www.smartydns.com/support/transparent-dns-proxy-test/) test confirmed it: someone/something between you and and the rest of the internet (most probably your ISP or compromised home router) is acting as ['Transparent DNS proxy'](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/what-is-transparent-dns-proxy.html), intercepting your DNS queries and redirecting them to their own DNS server.

If you want to be sure, since probably only UDP/TCP port 53 is intercepted, you can try changing BIND to [listen at some other port](http://www.golinuxhub.com/2012/08/change-port-no-for-dns-server.html), then test from both digital Ocean instance and your laptop with `dig` querying that new port:

`dig bubby.com @192.241.227.149 -p 5555`

You should this time get the same results.

Comment: This was absolutely the problem. After you suggested this, I went into my router settings and discovered that the router was getting DNS from my ISP. After setting it to my digital ocean instance, I got the same results as I was getting directly from the instance. Thank you!